# Как извлечь массив подстрок из строки

Tags: javascript, строки, парсер

Есть следующие строки:

```
`GUID={f3f459b9-597a-4f0a-9e46-71642eff8048} (Microphone)
 Path={0.0.1.00000000} {e5979f07-3b2d-4d10-8302-7078372cbc5b}
 Stations Mask=0xffff Effective Stations Mask=0xffff`
`CPU{Name[Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz] ProcID[BFEBFBFF000906E9]}
 DeviceId[\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1] Model[WDC WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0] S/N[ WD-WCATR6399959]`
```

На выходе хочу получить:

```
    {
GUID: '{f3f459b9-597a-4f0a-9e46-71642eff8048} (Microphone)',
path: '{0.0.1.00000000} {e5979f07-3b2d-4d10-8302-7078372cbc5b}',
stationsMask: '0xffff',
effectiveStationsMask: '0xffff',
}

CPU: {
  name: 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz',
  procID: 'BFEBFBFF000906E9',
}

{
deviceId: '/./PHYSICALDRIVE1',
model: 'WDC WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0',
S/N: 'WD-WCATR6399959',
}
```

Как решить такую задачу на JS? Думаю здесь нужно регулярным выражением, но составить не получается, знаний пока не хватает.

Comment: Если названия всегда одинаковы, тогда не вижу ничего сложного. И да, почему они на одной строке `Stations Mask=0xffff Effective Stations Mask=0xffff`?

Comment: Названия и количество строк могут меняться.  Скобки можно заменить на = ('DeviceId[\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1] Model[WDC WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0] S/N[ WD-WCATR6399959]' ===> `DeviceId=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 Model=WDC WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0] S/N= WD-WCATR6399959').
У меня проблема в том, что я  не могу сделать правильный массив через str.split(' ') так как пробелы тут не подходят. Они могут быть и в ключе и в значении.

Comment: Это не было бы проблемой, если бы все значения ключей были бы в квадратных скобках. Попросите поменять формат выдаваемой информации, в противоположном случае я не вижу способа определения ключей и значений